# React - storybook. Bootstrap Icon components don't show in storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, storybook

I am building React storybook components using react-bootstrap.
Almost components are completed well.
But only some components that includes bootstrap icons don't show in storybook.
Is there any way to fix this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";`
in the `.storybook/preview.js` file solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is for linked components, in this case, you need import each icon from SVG.

```
import {
  faEdit,
  faUser,
  faCartShopping,
  faHeart,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
```

Don't forget link the components in console with: npm link

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css";` in `.storybook/preview.js`, as mentioned by @li-1001 (note that I recommend using the minified version, though).
2. Add the `node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font` directory to statically served files. Otherwise you will get a 404, because the `bootstrap-icons.woff2` file can't be found. At least that's what I got.

So in `.storybook/main.js`, do:

```js
module.exports = {
    defaultSettings: {
        staticDirs: [
            '../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font',
        ],
        // ...
```

And adjust this `package.json` script:

`"build-storybook": "storybook build -s ../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font",`

`-s` can take a comma separated list, if you need to serve multiple static directories.